# Map over two arrays with jq and merge objects inside

Tags: json, merge, command-line-interface, jq

I have two arrays of identical length with objects in them:

```
input: [[{foo: 1}, {foo: 23}], [{bar: 12, baz: 543}, {bar: -1}]]
```

How do I tell [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to merge them into one array like below?

```
output: [{foo: 1, bar: 12, baz: 543}, {foo: 23, bar: -1}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses [transpose](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#transpose) and [add](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add).  Assuming the sample data is in `data.json`:

```
$ jq -M 'transpose|map(add)' data.json
[
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 12,
    "baz": 543
  },
  {
    "foo": 23,
    "bar": -1
  }
]
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/ger1zb3_xV)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stream-oriented solution using `zips/2` defined as follows:

```
# Input: an array, padded as necessary with null.
# Output: a stream with |stream| items, `[$in[$i], $s$i] | f`, 
# where $s$i is the $i-th item in the stream.
def zips(stream; f):
  . as $in | foreach stream as $x (-1; .+=1; [$in[.], $x] | f);
```

This avoids the overhead of `transpose`, and would be especially appropriate if the two arrays had not already been combined, or if a stream output was acceptable.

In any case, `zips` could be used as follows to solve the problem at hand:

```
. as $in
| $in[0] | [zips( $in[1][]; add )]
```

If you don't require the result to be a single array, you can omit the square brackets around the call to `zips`.